# How to use OnKeyup in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I want to use an event by leaving an input field in a matrix in JQuery. If the value is not a number you have to get a message "Value is not a number."

How do you do that?
We asp and jquery.

```
    $(window).keyup(function (e){
        var sCurrentValue = "";
        var sValue = "";
        for (var i=1; i<$("#Rows").val(); i++) {
            for (var j=1; j<=7; j++) {
                sCurrentValue = $(document.getElementById("inputfld" + j + "_" + i)).val();

                // If Current value has data and the value is not a number then we stop the procedure
                if (sCurrentValue.length > 0 && isNaN(sCurrentValue)) {
                    sValue = sCurrentValue;
                    bValueIsNumber = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!bValueIsNumber) {
            ShowMessage("Value [xxx] is not a number.");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to check which key event triggered. For example, e.keyCode == 13 means user press Enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not attach your listener to the whole document, attach it to the input elements only:

This will trigger on "enter" and "tab".

```
$("input").keyup(function(e) {
    if((e.which == 13) || (e.which == 9)) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(!validate(value)) {
            alert("validation failed");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This will trigger on "leaving the input field" as you requested:

```
$("input").blur(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(!validate(value)) {
        alert("validation failed");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you link it to to your object?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. $("input") attaches the listener to all of your input objects, and you refer to the currently active object within the listeners with $(this).

Comment: Sorry it's works. There were some errors to solve. Thanks for your help.